# Get List of Sockets with Winsock

Tags: python, c, windows, winsock2

How can I retrieve a list of all socket file descriptors in my process?
Is it possible to do this in Python or must I do this in C with Winsock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Python but I think the following code is easily portable.

I've used the following method on VxWorks frequently and quickly tried it on Windows to test if it works. The idea is to simply iterate sockets (= integers) and check if they are valid:

```
int iterator;
int len;
int option;

for (iterator = 1; iterator < 1024; iterator++)
{
    len = sizeof(option);
    if (getsockopt((SOCKET)iterator, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, &option, &len) == 0)   // valid socket?
    {
        /* valid socket found! */
    }
}
```

I've run it on Windows 7 with the following test application which creates some sockets:

```
int main ()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET s;
    int iterator;
    int option;
    int len;
    struct sockaddr_in sockaddr;



    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData);


    /*
    **  create some sockets...
    */
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    printf("s=%d\n", s);

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    printf("s=%d\n", s);
    sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.178.1");
    sockaddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    connect(s, (SOCKADDR *)&sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr));

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    printf("s=%d\n", s);
    sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    sockaddr.sin_port = htons(27015);
    bind(s, (SOCKADDR *)&sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr));
    listen(s, 10);



    printf("\niterating sockets...\n");
    for (iterator = 1; iterator < 1024; iterator++)
    {
        len = sizeof(option);
        if (getsockopt((SOCKET)iterator, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, &option, &len) == 0)   // valid socket?
        {
            printf("socket=%d (type=%d)\n", iterator, option);

            len = sizeof(option);
            if (getsockopt((SOCKET)iterator, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ACCEPTCONN, &option, &len) == 0)
            {
                if (option == 0)
                {
                    len = sizeof(sockaddr);
                    if (getpeername((SOCKET)iterator, (SOCKADDR *)&sockaddr, &len) == 0)
                    {
                        printf("   connected to %d.%d.%d.%d:%d\n",
                               sockaddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1,
                               sockaddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2,
                               sockaddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3,
                               sockaddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4,
                               sockaddr.sin_port);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("   ???\n");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    len = sizeof(sockaddr);
                    if (getsockname((SOCKET)iterator, (SOCKADDR *)&sockaddr, &len) == 0)
                    {
                        printf("   accepting connections on port=%d\n", sockaddr.sin_port);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("   accepting connections on port=???\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following printouts:

```
s=124
s=132
s=136

iterating sockets...
socket=124 (type=1)
   ???
socket=125 (type=1)
   ???
socket=126 (type=1)
   ???
socket=132 (type=1)
   connected to 192.168.178.1:20480
socket=133 (type=1)
   connected to 192.168.178.1:20480
socket=134 (type=1)
   connected to 192.168.178.1:20480
socket=136 (type=1)
   accepting connections on port=34665
socket=137 (type=1)
   accepting connections on port=34665
socket=138 (type=1)
   accepting connections on port=34665
```

Interestingly, it seems that Windows creates two additional sockets per socket returned by `socket(..)`. I briefly searched the internet to find some information about this but didn't find anything...

Comment: Great answer, but why do you arbitreraly stop at 1024? Is that the maximum number of sockets?

Comment: @user4257726 There is a constant called FD_SETSIZE (= 64 by default I think) which defines the maximum number of sockets for an application. But Windows starts creating sockets with an offset. So I just randomly picked a large number (in respect to FD_SETSIZE) to get all sockets...

Comment: BUt wouldn't it be possible for you to miss some of the sockets this way? Wouldn't you have to go up to MAX_INT to be sure that you got them all?

Comment: @user4257726 You're right, to make absolutely sure you have to check every possible value. But looking at FD_SETSIZE (which is fairly small) and an offset of somewhere close to 100 you're on the save side if you stop iterating at 10000. Also remember that each socket requires some memory (for I/O buffers, ...) as well so you'll never get 2^32 sockets...